# Force capitalize letters in domain name

Tags: http, dns, browser

So I understand the fact that domain names are case insensitive:

```
google.com, GOOGLE.COM, GooGLe.Com, gOOgle.cOm ===> google.com
```

but my question is: **Is it possible to force letters in a domain name to appear capitalized by default?**

For example, if I owned www.crazycapitalization.com is there any way I could make it appear as CrazyCapitaliZation.com by default whenever the domain was accessed?

```
crazycapitalization.com, CRAZYCAPITALIZATION.COM ===> CrazyCapitaliZation.com
```

If this cannot be done I would be curious to know why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes. I was just wondering if there was any way (via javascript or any other programatic solution) to manipulate the browser in a way to generate this type of behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The place to look this up is the [**Domain Names specification (RFC 2035)**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).

It states that *“while upper and lower case letters are allowed in domain names, no significance is attached to the case.  That is, two names with the same spelling but different case are to be treated as if identical.”* That's what you noted indeed.

Interestingly (and perhaps surprisingly to many), it also says that *“when data enters the domain system, its original case should be preserved whenever possible”* and *“future
additions beyond current usage may need to use the full binary octet capabilities in names, so attempts to store domain names in 7-bit ASCII or use of special bytes to terminate labels, etc., should be avoided.”*

So in the original design, there was a possibility to preserve the case (even though comparison always happens in a case-insensitive way). However, when it resolves a domain name, **your browser only asks the IP address** belonging to that domain (and not the “canonical” name). So even if a certain DNS server would store case (usually not, as far as I know), your browser wouldn't use that information.

So it *could* be done, but only with a specifically crafted browser (and perhaps DNS server).

The cool thing is: you would still be respecting the DNS protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So do you think it is a possibility that a future version of Chrome may be able to support force capitalization in domain names?

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept the answer if you like it?
I think it's very unlikely that Chrome would ever introduce this. That would change a practice that has been around since the beginning of the Web. Furthermore, what extra functionality would it bring? It might even bring more confusion (think fishing). And after all, lowercase and uppercase will always mean the same; that cannot be changed.

Comment: This _can_ be done, in fact I had a site a few years back, Word1Word2.com, where I forced capitalized the two words and most major browsers respected this.  I'm now looking to do this again and don't recall how I did it.  Searching forums atm - thats how I found the info last time